# Algorithm for IRI-to-URI/URI-to-IRI conversion

Tags: url, unicode, uri, ascii, iri

Are there any open source algorithms for converting an IRI to an URI and an URI to an IRI?

A C# implementation is preferable, but not necessary.

Comment: See `3.2.  Converting URIs to IRIs` http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt

Comment: @dand, I saw that.  I'm hoping there is an existing implementation before I write my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET 2.0 SP1 and later has built in support for IRI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968786.aspx